# integral of parametric equation

Tags: integration

Let g(x) =  $\int_{-1}^{2x+4} e^{-t^2} dt$

Find the value of g'(-2).

The answer is 2, but I don't know how to get there.

I thought that the derivative of the integral should just be $e^{-t^2}$ and so I would plug in -2 into 2x+4 and get the slope, but my answer of 1-e did not match the correct answer.

Please help, or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: I ultimately figured this out from this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COdMWnChXVM. I didn't know you had to calculate dt as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

If the upper bound had been $x+4$, then, using the fundamental theorem of calculus, you would have found that $g'(x)=e^{-(x+4)^2}$ for any $x$. But you have $2x+4$, so $g'(x)=2 e^{-(2x+4)^2}$ for any $x$. This is the chain rule problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Remember the chain rule.  If $F(s) = \int_{-1}^s e^{-t^2}\ dt$, then you do have $F'(s) = e^{-s^2}$, but here you're looking at $g(x) = F(2x+4)$.